# How to Filter/Search List in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, filtering

I am trying to think of a way to filter a list of buttons that I dynamically create, based on values looped through from the SQlite DB. Each button is tagged with a student name and there could be a large number of buttons, hence the need to filter the buttons.

I create my buttons as so:

```
public RectTransform GridWithNameElements;
public GameObject StudentNamePrefabButton;

while (reader.Read())
            {
                //create a new button object and use the prefab button to make sure spacing etc is correct
                goButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(StudentNamePrefabButton);
                //set the parent of the button
                goButton.transform.SetParent(GridWithNameElements, false);
                goButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
                //set the text of the button. Array value is 0 as the student name is always at position 0 on each iteration
                goButton.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[0].text = reader["fullName"].ToString()+" | "+ reader["studentNumber"].ToString();
                goButton.name = reader["studentID"].ToString();

                Button tempButton = goButton.GetComponent<Button>();
                int tempInt = i;

                tempButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(tempInt));

                i++;

                Debug.Log(goButton.name);
            }
```

Then I created an input field and attached a script to the `onValueChanged` in the input field and attempted to write a script.

```
//This method is called when the student attempts to search for their own name when taking the individual quiz
public void SearchExistingStudentName()
{

    //Get the name entered from the text field
    string student_name = searchExistingStudentNameInput.text;

    //Add names that exist to the new list
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    names.Clear();
    //sets an id to the onclick listener of newly created buttons
    int x = 0;

    //if a new button object exists and the name was entered and then removed, clear it from the list and remove the created button
    if (student_name == "")
    {
        //Clear the filtered names List
        names.Clear();
        x = 0;
        //Destroy the create filter buttons if the user clears the text area
        GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("filterButton");
        //loop through the buttons that share the tag "filterButton"
        for (int count = 0; count < objects.Length; count++)
        {
            Destroy(objects[count]);

            Debug.Log("Number of objects to be deleted " + objects.Length);
        }

        //Loop through and show all children 
        foreach (Transform child in GridWithNameElements)
        {
            child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        } 
    }
    else if (student_name != "")
    {
        int count = 0;
        int filteredNameCount = 0;
        int filteredIDCount = 1;
        //loop through the list of buttons with student names
        for (int i = 0; i < GridWithNameElements.childCount; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Children of grid "+GridWithNameElements.childCount);
            //Check if the user has typed their name with capitals or lowercase etc, and check the inputted value against names already in the list
            //If true, proceed 
            if (GridWithNameElements
               .GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.Contains(student_name) || GridWithNameElements
               .GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.ToLower().Contains(student_name) || GridWithNameElements
               .GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.ToUpper().Contains(student_name))
            {

                //If the name entered contains letters found in the parent GridWithNameElements, then add them to the list array and their name value (unique id)
                names.Add(GridWithNameElements.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.Replace(@"[", string.Empty).Replace(@"]", string.Empty));
                names.Add(GridWithNameElements.GetChild(i).name); //this is the unique id of the student

                Debug.Log("Number of items in filtered names list " + names.Count);

                //Loop through and hide all children and hide them
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    foreach (Transform child in GridWithNameElements)
                    {
                        child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }

                count++;

                //Then create a button that represents a name added to the names List
                newButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(StudentNamePrefabButton);
                //set the parent of the button
                newButton.transform.SetParent(GridWithNameElements, false);
                newButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
                //set the text of the button. Array value is 0 as the student name is always at position 0 on each iteration
                newButton.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[filteredNameCount].text = names[filteredNameCount].ToString();
                newButton.name = names[filteredIDCount].ToString().Trim();
                newButton.tag = "filterButton";

                filteredNameCount++;
                filteredIDCount++;


                //Then add a click listener to the button
                Button tempButton = newButton.GetComponent<Button>();
                int tempInt = x;

                tempButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(tempInt));

                x++;

                // Debug.Log("Student Unique ID " + newButton.name);


            }   
        }
        count = 0;
    }       
}
```

I was hoping to simply Loop through all list items, and hide those that don't match the search query. However, at the moment, my loop is wrong, as I get an out of bounds exception (which I think is to do with adding a new child element dynamically when making a search). I see this in the console log, however, the program executes as expected (so this is a problem, but currently not the biggest).

I am hiding the original list and showing the new list based on matching criteria.

However, I am only ever returning one possible name, rather than a bunch of possible choices. For example, if I had the name Ben Jones and Bob Dylan, based on my code at the moment, I am only ever able to return Ben Jones and never Bob Dylan.

I feel like I am going the wrong way around doing this because I want something similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp), and unable to recreate it. I am trying to figure out, however, if I am heading in the right direction or not.

UPDATE

I think I have found the reason for the `IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.` It is because whenever I type a letter, it is calling the `SearchExistingStudentName()` method. This means that as long as the letter typed is found within one of the names, it is added to list - only the letter. This is why I can only return one name, rather than a list of possible names. Therefore I think the if statement needs amending, which I am trying to look into now.

I have managed to narrow down the array exception in the code to this section:

```
//Loop through and hide all children and hide them
if (count == 0)
{
foreach (Transform child in GridWithNameElements)
  {
child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
  }
}

count++;

//Then create a button that represents a name added to the names List
newButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(StudentNamePrefabButton);
//set the parent of the button
newButton.transform.SetParent(GridWithNameElements, false);
newButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
//set the text of the button. Array value is 0 as the student name is always at position 0 on each iteration
newButton.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[filteredNameCount].text = names[filteredNameCount].ToString();
newButton.name = names[filteredIDCount].ToString().Trim();
                    newButton.tag = "filterButton";

filteredNameCount++;
filteredIDCount++;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `nameInList` variable inside the loop?

Comment: And what about use toggles? Maybe makes your life easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself in the end, and although it is far from an elegant solution, it works. I am now going to work on improving the code itself, but for those that might want a starting point, I thought I would share what I did.

As mentioned in my question, I loop out a bunch of buttons onto my main, unfiltered scrollable list as so.

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                //create a new button object and use the prefab button to make sure spacing etc is correct
                GameObject goButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(StudentNamePrefabButton);
                //set the parent of the button
                goButton.transform.SetParent(GridWithNameElements, false);
                goButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
                //set the text of the button. Array value is 0 as the student name is always at position 0 on each iteration
                goButton.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[0].text = reader["fullName"].ToString() + " | " + reader["studentNumber"].ToString();
                goButton.name = reader["studentID"].ToString();

                Button tempButton = goButton.GetComponent<Button>();
                int tempInt = i;

                tempButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(tempInt));

                i++;

                Debug.Log(goButton.name);
            }
```

I then created a user `inputfield` in my UI, so the user could search for their name. Then attached a listener. To do this go to the Unity editor and attach your script to the `On Value Changed` method.

Every-time a user then types into your `inputfield`, your attached script is called.

I then ended up doing the following - again, I stress, I have just got this working so not a perfect example, but at least a starting point and there might still be more bugs to sort out. I hope it helps someone as I didn't find any complete examples when I was looking.

```
//This method is called when the student attempts to search for their own name when taking the individual quiz
public void SearchExistingStudentName()
{

    //Get the name entered from the text field
    string student_name = searchExistingStudentNameInput.text;

    //Create a list to store all the user names
    List<string> filteredNamesList = new List<string>();
    //Add another list to store the user unique ids
    List<string> filteredNameIDList = new List<string>();

    //Clear both lists before using them
    filteredNamesList.Clear();
    filteredNameIDList.Clear();
    //sets an id to the onclick listener of newly created buttons
    int x = 0;

    //if a new button object exists and the name was entered and then removed, clear it from the list and remove the created button
    if (student_name == "")
    {
        //Clear the filtered filteredNamesList List
        filteredNamesList.Clear();
        filteredNameIDList.Clear();
        x = 0;
        //Destroy the create filter buttons if the user clears the text area
        GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("filterButton");
        //loop through the buttons that share the tag "filterButton"
        for (int count = 0; count < objects.Length; count++)
        {
            Destroy(objects[count]);

            Debug.Log("Number of objects to be deleted " + objects.Length);
        }

        //Loop through and show all children 
        foreach (Transform child in GridWithNameElements)
        {
            child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        GridWithNameElements.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        GridWithNameElements2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (student_name != "")
    {

        //loop through the list of buttons in the main/unfiltered list with student filteredNamesList
        for (int i = 0; i < GridWithNameElements.childCount; i++)
        {
            //Check if the user has typed their name with capitals or lowercase etc, and check the inputted value against filteredNamesList already in the list
            //If true, proceed 

            //Get the name value that contains entered character
            if (GridWithNameElements
               .GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.Contains(student_name) || GridWithNameElements
               .GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.ToLower().Contains(student_name) || GridWithNameElements
               .GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.ToUpper().Contains(student_name))
            {

                //Do not allow duplicates to the list
                if (filteredNamesList.Distinct().Count() == filteredNamesList.Count())
                {
                    //If the name entered contains letters found in the parent GridWithNameElements, then add them to the list array and their name value (unique id)
                    filteredNamesList.Add(GridWithNameElements.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[i].text.Replace(@"[", string.Empty).Replace(@"]", string.Empty));
                    filteredNameIDList.Add(GridWithNameElements.GetChild(i).name); //this is the unique id of the student
                }

                //end of if statement   
            }
            //end of main loop
        }
        //hide original list
        GridWithNameElements.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        //show filtered list
        GridWithNameElements2.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        //Destroy the created filter buttons if the user presses another button, as previously 
        //added filteredNamesList might need to be ruled out. 
        GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("filterButton");
        //loop through the buttons that share the tag "filterButton"
        for (int count = 0; count < objects.Length; count++)
        {
            Destroy(objects[count]);

            Debug.Log("Number of objects to be deleted " + objects.Length);
        }

        int filteredNameIDCount = 0;

        foreach (string nameInList in filteredNamesList)
        {


            //Then create a button that represents a name added to the filteredNamesList List
            newButton = Instantiate(StudentNamePrefabButton);
            //set the parent of the button
            newButton.transform.SetParent(GridWithNameElements2, false);
            newButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            //set the text of the button. Array value is 0 as the student name is always at position 0 on each iteration
            newButton.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[0].text = nameInList.ToString();
            newButton.name = filteredNameIDList[filteredNameIDCount].ToString().Trim();
            newButton.tag = "filterButton";

            Debug.Log("Filtered Name " + nameInList.ToString() + " Their ID " + filteredNameIDList[filteredNameIDCount].ToString().Trim());

            filteredNameIDCount++;

        }
        //end of loop


        //Then add a click listener to the button
        Button tempButton = newButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        int tempInt = x;

        tempButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(tempInt));

        x++;

        // Debug.Log("Student Unique ID " + newButton.name);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged this with Unity3D I'm assuming you are looking to use this code in a game. If that is the case I would not recommend using LINQ, if the same result can easily be obtained in a more traditional way. That being said, I'll show both ways to do it.

```
List<string> names = GridWithNameElements.Where(nameInList => nameInList.Contains(input))
```

The above finds all the names where `nameInList.Contains(input)` evalutes to `true`.

In a loop you'd do the following.

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach (string nameInList in GridWithNameElements)
{
    if (nameInList.Contains(input)
    {
        names.Add(nameInList)
    }
}
```

I am not entirely confident on the types of the variables but I think the structure should be clear enough. Feel free to ask some more if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added more detail to my question since you posted this, as I feel the solution is a little more complex than originally explained. I am unable to use your syntax of `string nameInList` as I get an `error of cannot cast from source type to destination type`. I am using a simple for loop instead now as shown in the update. I am further than I was, but as the updated question suggests, there are still some bugs.